# How to send email using PHP on Windows?

Tags: php, windows

My code is not working, how can I solve this problem? I want to receive mail on my Yahoo ID.

```
<?php
  // the message
  $msg = "First line of text\nSecond line of text";

  // use wordwrap() if lines are longer than 70 characters
  $msg = wordwrap($msg,70);

  // send email
  mail("faisalkhan00668@yahoo.com","My subject",$msg);
?>
```

The error:

> Warning: mail() [function.mail]: "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\mail.php on line 9

Comment: try [sendmail.exe](http://blog.techwheels.net/send-email-from-localhost-wamp-server-using-sendmail/)

Comment: btw you can not use mail() with a standard xampp installation, because you probably have no webserver installed on it

Comment: yes but email not sent

Answer (score 5):

In the fourth parameter you can add headers to the mail. Here you can add your from:

explained on the php site here
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

```
$to      = 'nobody@example.com';
$subject = 'the subject';
$message = 'hello';
$headers = 'From: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

This will fix the from problem

Now in php.ini there is a line

```
;sendmail_from = postmaster@localhost
```

If you uncomment this by removing the `;` you can set a default. in which case you won't have to add headers to the `mail()` call.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using SMTP? try to insert those 2 lines at the beginning of your php code:

`ini_set ("SMTP","localhost");
ini_set ("sendmail_from","xxxyourmailxxx@xxxxxx.xxx");`

Comment: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: Failed to connect to mailserver at "localhost" port 25, verify your "SMTP" and "smtp_port" setting in php.ini or use ini_set() in C:\xampp\htdocs\mail\mail.php on line 11  still this error is occur

Comment: Try this:
$headers="From: mittente@mail.it";

mail("faisalkhan00668@yahoo.com","My subject",$msg,$headers);

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using the mail() function. Please remember that this will not work on a local server.

```
<?php
    $to      = 'faisalkhan00668@yahoo.com';
    $subject = 'My subject';
    $message = 'hello';
    'Reply-To: webmaster@example.com' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    mail($to, $subject, $message);
 ?>
```

To create an SMTP server you need to do the following:

Create SMTPConfig.php

```
<?php
//These need to be changed to actual values
    $SmtpServer="127.0.0.1";
    $SmtpPort="25"; //default
    $SmtpUser="username";
    $SmtpPass="password";
?>
```

add the following code to the index.php file:

```
<?php
   include('SMTPconfig.php');
   include('SMTPClass.php');

   if($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
       $to = $_POST['to'];
       $from = $_POST['from'];
       $subject = $_POST['sub'];
       $body = $_POST['message'];
       $SMTPMail = new SMTPClient ($SmtpServer, $SmtpPort, $SmtpUser, $SmtpPass, $from,                    $to, $subject, $body);
       $SMTPChat = $SMTPMail->SendMail();
   }
  ?>
  <form method="post" action="">
  To:<input type="text" name="to" />
  From :<input type='text' name="from" />
  Subject :<input type='text' name="sub" />
  Message :<textarea name="message"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" value=" Send " />
```